# Regex needed for parsing a date/time string

Tags: regex, datetime

Can someone provide me with a regex for the following? (Using Javascript)

source string: `Jan 2 2010 6:00PM`

I want the resulting string to show only the time, as shown below. (example above used)

result string: `6:00 PM`

Comment: platform of choice? Also, SilentGhost has a very good point

Comment: why do you need regex? can't you split the string on the last space?

Comment: I agree that split would be good. Why didn't I think of that? (duh)
However, how would I split the PM off in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})([AP]M)` with `\1 \2`

Update: Use `\d{2}` instead of `\d{1,2}` if the source string is guaranteed to be in the `HH:MM` format.

Comment: +1, but `:\d{1,2}` should be `:\d{2}`, as seconds always uses 2 digits

Comment: Ya, I was just being lenient - hour part in OP's example was single digit.

Comment: Rubens: I see no seconds, but minutes! :P

Comment: 99:77PM will be okay by this pattern. SimpleDateFormat is best.

Comment: This is for extracting time from a given date-time string - not for validating time in any given string.

Comment: Amarghosh: HH:MM isn't guaranteed, the example doesn't even follow that.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing SilentGhost's comment in regex: `/([^ ]+)([^ ]{2})$/`

This will match the last space-delimited "word", with the first bit in group 1 and the last two chars in group 2.  The translation to string operations instead should be straight-forward.

You could also replace the `(..)` with `[AP]M` or similar, if desired, and might benefit from a tiny bit of validation if you construct the regex to prevent something like `blah blah haha-I-gave-garbage-inputPM`, but there are many ways to deal with garbage anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SimpleDateFormat` with the format `MMM dd yyyy HH:mm`. Then you can get the time part.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't looked I'm sure you'll be able to find something that will work for you at the [Regex Library](http://www.regexlib.com) website. However I happen to agree with SilentGhost in that it might be easier to just split the string. Just make sure all DateTimes are are in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert it into a date object, and if you're using Javascript in a web browser, you might want this instead:

```
new Date('Jan 2 2010 6:00PM'.replace(/(?=[AP]M)/i, ' '));
// Sat Jan 02 2010 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

new Date('Jan 2 2010 6:00PM'.replace(/(?=[AP]M)/i, ' ')).toUTCString();
// Sun, 03 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT
```

Mozilla has reference documentation on the [Javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date).